# switch style sheet based on Twig hash interation and meeting if condition

Tags: php, hashmap, twig

I've not used twig much and I'm struggling with a simple bit of switching. I want to progressively change from font icons to an svg library a page at a time. The idea is to add the changed page uri to the array then have twig chose the correct stylesheet. Though it's not working. Any help provided would be appreciated.

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
      {# Add URI of pages which have svg icons to this hash #}
      {% set pages_with_icons_available = ['/']%}

      {# Iterates over hash to display the appropriate style sheet#}
      {% for page in pages_with_icons_available %}           
        {% if currentUri == {{page}} %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/styles.css')|add_asset_version }}" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/print.css')|add_asset_version }}" media="print"/>
        {% else %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/styles-with-icon-font.css')|add_asset_version }}" media="screen"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/print.css')|add_asset_version }}" media="print"/>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endblock stylesheets %}
```

Comment: It is `currentUri == page`

Comment: `{% if currentUri == {{page}} %}`. This is wrong `{{ }}` is used to output stuff. You are already in a statement, just use `{% if currentUri == page %}`

Comment: Change `currentUri == {{ page }}` to `currentUri == page`

Comment: You wonderfull people! thank you!